# How to extract unique values from a range in VBA per criteria

Tags: vba

I want to create a list of unique values based on a range per criteria.

I have a list of exceptions in worksheet "RawData" column "AG" which I want to extract to worksheet "Incidents" Column "I".

The criteria is the country code which is in worksheet "RawData" column "O".

So to summarize I want the exceptions listed per country in column "I" (worksheet Incidents) and the country code in column C (worksheet Incidents) extracted from worksheet RawData.

So far I have the following :

```
Sub Extract_Unique()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim destrng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("RawData").Range("AG2:AG15000")

Set destrng = Worksheets("Incidents").Range("I2")

Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Rng, _
CopyToRange:=destrng, unique:=True


End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. Some sample data and expected output might help clarify things.

Comment: Your code works for me. What's the problem?